# How to config pip.ini asking for credentials?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm distribute python 3.9.7 and **pip 21.2.3** in my department over chocolatey as upgrade to python 3.6.3 for windows. Pip shall get packages from our own artifactory (jfrog) repo.
In a previous version my %appdata%\pip\pip.ini file looked like this:

```
[global]
index-url = https:\\<username>@<artifactoryserver>/<piprepo>
```

As the password is missing, the previous version of pip asked for the credentials, when some tried to install a python plugin, but with **pip 21.2.3** it says immediately wrong credentials. Because of security reasons, it is not allowed to store a apikey for artifactory readable in pip.ini in my department.

*Do you have an idea to configure **pip 21.2.3** asking for credentials in windows when installing a python plugin from an own pip-repository?*

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug which has been fixed in PIP 21.3. Check the release notes:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/

> Fix the auth credential cache to allow for the case in which the index url contains the username, but the password comes from an external source, such as keyring. (#10269)

If possible upgrade to the latest PIP version 21.3.1 and see if it helps.